# Which outofbox webpart shld be used to show an image and redirect the image ? 

Tags: web-part

I need to use any of the out of the box webpart ,
my requirement is , the webpart consist of an image and it shld redirect to a page .

Comment: i got it . .
1)add a content editor webpart . . 
2)go to rich text editor . . 
3)press ctr+shift + g and browse and add the image . . 
4)on top nav press  " click to open hyperlink in new window "
5) say ok . .

ur ready to go /  /

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2010

- Add "Content Editor Webpart"
- Select content editing area of webpart
- In ribbon, Editing Tools -> Insert -> Picture -> From Address
- Address = /sites/test/SiteAssets/a.gif
- In ribbon, Editing Tools -> Format Text -> HTML -> Edit HTML Source

Change

```
<img alt="a" src="/sites/test/SiteAssets/a.gif" style="margin: 5px"/><br/><br/>
```

To

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img alt="a" src="/sites/test/SiteAssets/a.gif" style="margin: 5px"/></a><br/><br/>
```

- Then Save & Close